# Is this sentence correct with the usage of 'and'?

Tags: grammar

I really need to get these documents copied and in the mail but i have a meeting in an hour.

In this sentence, is it correct to connect 'copied' and 'in the mail' with 'and'?

Comment: It's more usual to coordinate elements which are the same parts of speech (bacon, eggs, and beans // signed, sealed and delivered) or similar parts of sentences (We went to Rome and they stayed in Paris // He ran down the road and into the park). But this example sounds unremarkable and clear. A comma or dash after 'mail' might be considered an improvement, and it's conventional to capitalise 'I'.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think now I am able to understand the usage of and.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence itself is correct, but it's also ambiguous. It would be clearer if it was written as:

> I really need to get these documents copied and [*posted* **or** *sent in the mail*], but I have a meeting in an hour.